# PHP array merge / map of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one that contains all options, and a second one that contains the default values.

The options arrays looks like this:

```
$options = array(
   "SeriesA" => array(
       "A1" => array(
          "text" => "A1",
          "value" => "A-001"
        ),
       "A2" => array(
          "text" => "A2",
          "value" => "A-002"
        )
    ),
  "SeriesB" => array(
       "B1" => array(
          "text" => "B2",
          "value" => "B-001"
        ),
       "B2" => array(
          "text" => "B2",
          "value" => "B-002"
        )
    ),
);
```

And I have another array that contains default value, and it looks like this

```
$defaults= array(
   "SeriesA" => "A-002",
   "SeriesB" => "B-001",
);
```

What I would like to end up with is one array that contains all info,
is there a way that I can map both arrays and get one array that will look like this:

```
$options = array(
   "SeriesA" => array(
       "A1" => array(
          "text" => "A1",
          "value" => "A-001",
          "default" => false
        ),
       "A2" => array(
          "text" => "A2",
          "value" => "A-002",
          "default" => true
        )
    ),
  "SeriesB" => array(
       "B1" => array(
          "text" => "B2",
          "value" => "B-001",
          "default" => true
        ),
       "B2" => array(
          "text" => "B2",
          "value" => "B-002",
          "default" => false
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: Just make a foreach loop wich is testing wich array in the series array is the default, and put a "default" => true value in the array. In every other array in a series array, put a "default" => false value.

Comment: Is this coming from a database? If so you can do this all in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two ways to do it:

Make a function, which accepts two args and check value in a loop with defaults, add defaults, and returns new array, or edit array, passing it by reference:

```
function awesomeName(&$options, $defaults) {
    foreach ($options as $k => &$values) {
        foreach ($values as &$AsAndBs) {
            $AsAndBs['default'] = $AsAndBs['value'] == $defaults[$k];
        }
    }
}
```

Using array_walk() function with anonymous function:

```
array_walk($options, function (&$v, $k) use ($defaults) {
    $series = $k;
    foreach ($v as &$series_contents) {
        $series_contents['default'] = $series_contents['value'] == $defaults[$series];
    }
});
```